# iis 7 response slow even on localhost with a text file

Tags: windows-server-2008, web-server, iis-7

My server (windows 2008 r2) began serving files really really slowly in IIS 7 after I rebooted the machine.

To test what was causing this I created a file "test.txt" on the site directory and accessed it via

```
"http://127.0.0.1/test.txt"
```

and it took at least 5 minutes to load, the file has the contents

```
"This is a test file".
```

I am assuming it is an IIS configuration setting, but I cannot find anything that would make it run this slow.

I also tested this in chrome dev tools, the network tab says the entire delay is "waiting (TTFB)"

Is there some configuration that affects file serving time?

I cannot find anything else that would make it run slow, cpu is less than 5% during request.

Comment: Anything else acting slowly on the machine?  Underlying storage behaving ok?

Comment: Were there any updates installed before the reboot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the comments on the original question, storage was fine and everything else normal.
I even started a temporary node js server to test network speed and it was blazing fast.
No updates were installed prior to the reboot (there were 2 months earlier).

The answer ended up being to restart the machine a second time. It just "fixed itself".

Always try the dumb stuff first.. Thanks for the ideas